# I want to write inner join in SOQL i was search but i couldnt found and my thought its a big problem

Tags: soql, inner-join

I try this code its was send this message i couldnt found well answer

Note: I want to make innerJoin Account to Contact like this,
And i am sure already each other have a releationship

```
Select  Owner_Plasiyer__c from Account 
where OWNER_ID__c in (Select ACCT_OWNER_ID__c from Contact)
```

And this is my error message

```
semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use: 'ACCT_OWNER_ID__c'
```

Comment: What are the field types of `OWNER_ID__c` and `ACCT_OWNER_ID__c`? (Please [edit]). A description in words of what your query is trying to do may also help.

Comment: I checked my fields type text and probably its a problem i'ill try know thanks.

Comment: It's still a good idea to [edit] your question to explain (using words) what you're trying to do with this query. Concepts from SQL don't necessarily carry over into SOQL (I think SOQL is closer to an Object-Relational Mapper like Hibernate [Java] or Doctrine [PHP]). If you're trying to retrieve both `Account` and `Contact` records through this query, you'll need to adjust your approach somewhat. As is, this query will only return `Account` records to you.

Comment: Are you just trying to find Account records which are associated to a Contact?

Comment: No i just trying if  Account Owner_id = Contact Owner_id get Account Data that is simple i can in sql but soql different more than :D and i am new i hope so i can i'ill try again

Comment: I think you would be better off by just breaking this into 2 queries. Get the result of Select ACCT_OWNER_ID__c from Contact into a list and use that list in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments (which really should be a part of your question proper), what you're trying to do is find Accounts that have at least one Contact where the Contact Owner and the Account Owner are the same.

Unfortunately, you'll need to break this into two separate queries, or do some processing in Apex, because SOQL doesn't allow field names to appear in the right-hand side of a filter expression (i.e. `WHERE OwnerId = Account.OwnerId` isn't allowed).

Just one of those things that we have to live with when dealing with Salesforce.

The other thing you should take into consideration here is *query selectivity*. If you have enough records (>= 200,000) and try to query *all* of them at once, Salesforce will complain. We developers have the responsibility of making sure that our queries return a reasonable set of results by applying filters on indexed fields (Id, Name, Email, any lookup fields, text fields marked as being an "external id", etc...).

Probably your best bet here is to first query a subset of your Accounts, and include the Contacts related to each Account via a sub-query (a left outer join, basically).

`[SELECT Id, OwnerId, (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE <some filters to make your query selective>]`

You could then iterate over the returned `Accounts`, and do an inner loop over the `Contacts` related to each `Account` to test if the Contact and Account OwnerId match.

If so, you can add the current `Account` to a collection and break out of the inner loop (or just use a collection type like a Set or Map to avoid getting duplicate Accounts in the collection)

Comment: Yesss got it thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi again i try to your answer i get information but without 'Where'  Do you have any suggestions about with syntax because after i'ill get informations on php

Comment: @FurkanKuyular The `WHERE` clause is pretty much the same as any other query language (again, with the exception of not being able to compare two fields to each other directly). If it helps, the [documentation on the WHERE clause is here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm).

Comment: Thanks For your answer again i'ill check :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can take when you want to compare two fields in a query (which I always seem to forget about) is to create a *formula field* to do your comparison for you.

The formula field takes care of the field-field comparison (`Contact.OwnerId == Account.OwnerId`)
Then your query uses the result of that formula field (`FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE <formula field api name> = true)`)